# jQuery.html() function strips textarea values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replacewith

I put together a jsfiddle to demonstrate an issue where I'm loosing `<textarea>` values when using `jQuery.html()` or `jQuery.replaceWith()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/wsams/Hxehg/2/

If you append a bit of text to the `<textarea>` and then click the `click me` text, see the console, the `textarea` value is stripped.

I'm expecting the values of each `<textarea>` to be preserved. Any ideas on how to do this or what's going on? Thanks

Comment: Because you're destroying the textarea and creating a new one...

Comment: When you update the **value** of a textarea, its **html** is unaffected.

Comment: Use `.val()` to extract the value. Use `.html()` to extract the **original** HTML. Which one do you really want?

Comment: The larger problem I'm trying to solve is replacing an element that has child textareas. Those textareas will have been updated prior to the replacement. I want to preserve those values.

Comment: One thought I have is to grab all of the values and store them somewhere, perform the replacement, and put the values back. Maybe my only option?